# Google Calendar API for .Net: Email notifications not sent when creating calendar event

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a windows service that uses the Google Calendar API v3 to create and delete calendar events.  My code is working, but when creating new events, email notifications never get sent to the invitees.  The events just show up on their calendar.

Here is a code snippet:

```
EventsResource.InsertRequest insertRequest = new EventsResource.InsertRequest(calendarService, eventRequest, calendarID);
insertRequest.SendNotifications = true;
var response = insertRequest.Execute();
```

I have tested creating the same events using the same authentication credentials using the Google Calendar API explorer:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#try-it

When I create the event using that form, email notifications are sent out correctly, so I don't think it's a configuration or authentication problem on the Google side.  I'm starting to think this is a bug in the Google API for .Net (I'm using the latest version - 1.8.1.95). I'm setting SendNotification property to true, but maybe it's not getting added to the actual request that goes out?

Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Could you print the http request and check whether it has the correct parameter?

Comment: I actually tried to find a way to do that, but couldn't figure it out.  The HTTP request is constructed under the hood in the Google API assemblies.  I could only debug it to the point where InsertRequest.Execute() is called, and the request at that point has the SendNotifications parameter set to true.  I tried monitoring with WireShark to see the HTTP request go out, but the data is encrypted.  Maybe there's another way to see the actual HTTP request that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Is it possible that the event you are creating is in the past?

Comment: No, I tried several different dates for creating events, and all were in the future - various days later this week.  And I plugged the exact same data into the Calendar API explorer, and when submitted from there, the event notifications get sent out correctly.

Comment: Could you check whether it worked fine in the previous version, for example: Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 Client Library 1.8.1.840 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/)

Comment: I rolled back to 1.8.1.840 and tested, and the notifications were sent correctly.  I then updated back to 1.8.1.950, and tested again, and the notifications still work.  Not sure what to think... maybe something went wrong when I installed the library the first time?  At any rate, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

```
Event EventNew = new Event();
/*Complete the event*/
EventNew.Summary = "test";
EventNew.Description = ....
EventNew. ......

 EventsResource.InsertRequest request = CalendarioGoogle.Events.Insert(EventNew,calendarID);

request.SendNotifications = true;


/*In this case result is a Event*/
result = request.Execute();
```