# Can't find sendNotifications option Google Calendar api v3 .NET

Tags: c#, php, .net, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm testing out the `Google Calendar API v3` on `.Net`. I've managed to add an event to a calendar as follows:

```
Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventAttendee attendee = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventAttendee();
attendee.Email = "[email]@gmail.com";

List<Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventAttendee> event_attendees = new List<Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventAttendee>();
event_attendees.Add(attendee);

Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event new_event = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event();

new_event.Summary = "GoogleCalendarTest: Testing Event 4";
new_event.Description = "Testing .Net Google Calendar API";
new_event.Location = "Offices";

new_event.Start = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventDateTime();
new_event.Start.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

new_event.End = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.EventDateTime();
new_event.End.DateTime = new DateTime(2014, 12, 15, 12, 0, 0);

new_event.Attendees = event_attendees;

service.Events.Insert(new_event, "[email]@gmail.com").Execute();
```

I thought this would automatically send an invite email to the attendee but it seems that by default it is not sent as seen here in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request). The `sendNotifications` parameter is added is an optional parameter, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19376407/1275525) shows how it's done on `PHP` but I can't figure how to add this on `.Net`.

**UPDATE**

Figured out a way to set `sendNotifications` on `.Net`:

```
Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.EventsResource.InsertRequest insert_event = new EventsResource.InsertRequest(service, new_event, "[email]@gmail.com");
insert_event.SendNotifications = true;
insert_event.Execute();
```

Still not sending an invitation email though, might still be doing something wrong.

**UPDATE 2**

Version issue?

I've found this question: [Google Calendar API for .Net: Email notifications not sent when creating calendar event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966477/google-calendar-api-for-net-email-notifications-not-sent-when-creating-calenda), which is very similar to the problem I have. Uninstalling and installing the API solved the problem...I tried this out but still have the same problem, currrent version: 1.9.0

Comment: Can you check whether in the attende's calendar settings(calendar->Editnotifications->New events) email is selected or not? If this is not selected eventhough send notifications is "True" still attendes don't get the notification

Comment: Yep Email is selected for all update notifications....new events, changed events, canceled events and event responses. I've tested out updating and deleting an event, it's still not sending any emails.

Comment: I tried as the same way but unable to send notification email.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
EventsResource.InsertRequest request = service.Events.Insert(newEvent, "primary");
request.SendNotifications = true;
Event createdEvent = request.Execute();
```